# Microsoft Band - Sample sound recording?

Tags: microsoft-band

Is this possible to record short, sample sound (like 10-15 sec) and store on paired phone/device?

Allowing user to gather sample sound from environment would be rally beneficial to our product.

Comment: It would be great if Microsoft release it API for the microphone in public ^^

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately the Microsoft Band does not support this feature and the microphone is not exposed via an API of the current SDK https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK

Answer (score 0):

As danvy has said, unfortunately it isn't available within the SDK to access the microphone.

If there is enough voice from developers for this to be added, I'm sure that the Microsoft Band team would be happy to expose more of the features in the Band to developers through the SDK. There is a [UserVoice](https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band) site just for the Microsoft Health & Band team which you can ask for these sorts of features but I'm also sure that they check here too!